# Values don't change in extension method (C#)

Tags: c#, vector, extension-methods

I'm writing a plugin for a CAD-system. Unfortunately this system has a bad API. So, I wrote the extension for Vector3d class. Here it is (C# code):

```
/// <summary>
///     Normalizes the vector by dividing it’s all coordinates with the vector's norm.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="v">
///     This vector.
/// </param>
/// <returns>
///     Returns vector's norm.
/// </returns>
public static double Normalize(this Vector3d v)
{
    var norm = v.Norm();
    var invNorm = 1.0 / norm;

    v.X *= invNorm;
    v.Y *= invNorm;
    v.Z *= invNorm;

    return norm;
}
```

But I have a problem: when this method is executing then the vector's coordinates are changed. But, when the method have executed, vector's coordinates have the original values.

I haven't problems with other extension methods.

Comment: Let me guess, `Vector3d` is a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As leppie mentioned, `Vector3d` is probably a [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx), rather than a class.

This means it's a [value type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), and passing it as a parameter to your extension method effectively creates a copy of the object. Your extension method changes the copy, which is then discarded when the method is exited.

I cannot find a good API reference for this .NET API, but this is probably also the reason why you perceive the API to be "bad". Methods that modify the Vector3d will return a copy of the original vector, rather than operating on the object itself. Alternatively, they could be using reference parameters, which is what you could do as well:

```
public static double Normalize(ref Vector3d v)
```

Assuming it is a struct (I cannot think of another explanation without more info), the creator of the API should have made the struct immutable however. Mutable structs are a recipe for problems such as these.

Personally, I would probably write your method like this:

```
public static Vector3d Normalize(this Vector3d v, out double norm)
{
    norm = v.Norm();
    var invNorm = 1.0 / norm;

    // Using a constructor with x, y, z parameters would be preferable,
    // if it exists.
    v.X *= invNorm;
    v.Y *= invNorm;
    v.Z *= invNorm;

    return v;
}
```

Unlike the `ref` option, it can be written as an extension method.

Comment: +1. It could also be read only property of reference type returning copy of the inner field, but it is way more likely to be value type (would be better if it is immutable type - such code would cause more obvious errors).

Comment: On `ref` - in many cases it would not be useful (i.e. property with value type always returns copy...).

Answer (score 1):

Working under the assumption that Vector3d is a struct:

The parameter (regardless of being the 'this' parameter of an extension method or not) is passed by value. The parameter that you use is actually a copy of the original vector3.

Suggest to change it to:

```
public static double NormalizeVector3d(ref Vector3d v);
```

Or:

```
public static Vector3d GetNormalizedVector3d(Vector3d v, out double norm);
```

Either way, it's not possible to do the call using an extension method.